# Shortest syntax to assign properties from function call to an existing object?

Tags: javascript

I have an existing object.

```
const existingObj = {
    //some existing properties
}
```

I have a function call that returns an object.

```
fn();
```

I know that I can assign properties from the function call to the existing object like this.

```
const res = fn()
existinObj.new1 = res.new1;
existingObj.new2 = res.new2;
```

Is there a shorter syntax I can use? Maybe even some syntax where I don't need to have a `res` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? You can use the spread operator here instead of assigning the value to every property

Keep in mind: If there is already an property with the same keyname then `fn()` will override it.

```js
function fn() {
   return {
      name1: "Max",
      name2: "lisa"
   }
}

let existingObject = { name3: "tim" }

existingObject = { ...existingObject, ...fn() };

console.log(existingObject);
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid property id referred to ```existingObject = { ...existingObject, ...fn() };```

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner what do you want to say with that?

Comment: That's the error I get in the browser's console (Firefox). And this is what I get running the above code snippet: Error: 
{
  "message": "SyntaxError: invalid property id",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 21,
  "colno": 19
}

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_colon_after_property_id see if you dont dit some mistakes listed here

Comment: I've copied and pasted your JS code, without changing anything. I get the same error running the above code snippet.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner you either did some mistake or your browser is too old

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.assign()`

```js
function makeObject()
{
    return {
        id: 20,
        cookie: "chocolate"
    };
}
let someObject = {
    id: 30,
    coffee: "black"
};
Object.assign(someObject, makeObject());
console.log(someObject);
```

Comment: Good solution, good code example, could also have been an accepted answer. Chose Ifraukis because I asked for the shortest one, and the spread operator uses fewer characters than Object.assign. I guess yours are different because your solution adds properties to an existing object while his creates a new object. Both solutions would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread operator `...` if the object names that are returned from the function are the same as the one in your object. This would look like this:

```js
function fn(){
  return {
    a: 5,
    b: 7
  };
}

const myObj = { ...fn() };

console.log(myObj);
```

Very nice shorthand ES6 Syntax

Comment: You would need to change that to const myObj = { ...myObj, ...fn() }; to not drop the existing properties, otherwise good solution

Comment: @user1283776 as it's a constant and it's newly created here, there are new other properties. But yeah, if you object already has properties, you need to add that as well